# How to design a distributed write-heavy data store

Tags: architecture, distributed-system, system-design, distributed-database

It's actually an interview question I'm thinking of for 2 month and can't find a suitable architecture.

**The problem**

We want to build a small analytics system for fraud detection on orders.

System has the following requirements

- Not allowed to use any technology from the market (`MySql`, `Redis`, `Hadoop`, `S3` etc)
- Needs to scale as the data volume grows
- Just a bunch of machines, with disks and decent amount of memory
- **10M** Writes/Day

The system needs to provide following **API**

- `/insertOrder(order): Order` 
   Add an order to the storage. The order can be considered blob with **1-10KBs** in size, with an `orderId` , `beginTime`, and `finishTime` as distinguished fields
- `/getLongestNOrdersByDuration(n: int, startTime: datetime, endTime: datetime): Order[]` 
   Retrieve the longest **N** orders that started between `startTime` and `endTime`,
   as measured by duration `finishTime - beginTime`
- `/getShortestNOrdersByDuration(n: int, startTime: datetime, endTime: datetime): Order[]` 
   Retrieve the shortest **N** orders that started between `startTime` and `endTime`,
   as measured by duration `finishTime - beginTime`

Comment: Can you further comment what you mean by "Not allowed to use any technology from the market"? I would take a look at the concepts of streaming processing and event driven solutions. An order could be considered an event stored in an event store. Streaming processing allows you to continuously analyse the events as they occur triggering other events for interested parties in case of fraudulous attempts.

Comment: I am not sure if you are allowed to consider solutions like Kafka? It is able to fulfil the design constraints of scalability, a bunch of machines and 10M writes/day (depending on the hardware specs and number of nodes in your cluster of course). If not allowed to evaluate such solutions, I wonder why not?

Comment: @KDW it's an artificial restriction since the problem is an interview question and tests the ability to make it up by ourselves

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Look at using druid database. If you time series data

- It should scale well with as volume of data grows
- Time duration queries can be answered effectively

https://druid.apache.org/ - This has been used as analytics db at scale in Fortune 500 companies

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The description mentions "Not allowed to use any technology from the market", therefore using Druid is not acceptable.